# Most concise way to return a certain value if "IndexOutOfBounds" in a multidimensional array

Tags: c#, arrays

For example; given a 2D array `int[,] arr = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};` & a Sum function

```
int Sum(int[,] arr, int ix, int iy) => 
                            arr[ix - 1, iy - 1] + arr[ix - 1, iy] + arr[ix - 1, iy + 1] +
                            arr[ix    , iy - 1] + arr[ix    , iy] + arr[ix    , iy + 1] +
                            arr[ix + 1, iy - 1] + arr[ix + 1, iy] + arr[ix + 1, iy + 1];
```

The following piece of code will error:

```
for(int i = 0; i < sx; ++i) 
    for(int j = 0; j < sx; ++j) 
        Console.Write("{0} ", Sum(arr, i, j));
```

Specifically, it will result in `Err Err Err Err 45 Err Err Err Err`.

But say I wish to default it to `0`, if the array cannot be accessed by a certain index; i.e. I wish the output to be `12 21 16 27 45 33 24 39 28`.

Another example would be the array `bool[,] arr = {{false, false, false}, {true, false, false}, {false, false, true}}` with the function

```
bool Or(bool[,] arr, int ix, int iy) => 
                            arr[ix - 1, iy - 1] || arr[ix - 1, iy] || arr[ix - 1, iy + 1] ||
                            arr[ix    , iy - 1] || arr[ix    , iy] || arr[ix    , iy + 1] ||
                            arr[ix + 1, iy - 1] || arr[ix + 1, iy] || arr[ix + 1, iy + 1];
```

With a default of `false`, it should result in `true true false true true true true true true`.(same printing method as above)

What is the most concise way of implementing such function for 2D arrays, or multidimensional arrays in general in C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [sentinel value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value) would be an easy and  concise to achieve what you want - just have your array surrounded by "default" values (0/false) and make sure you iterate inside that "safe boundary".

If changing the array is not an option writing helper method to get an element would keep length and structure of the code the same.

```
T Get<T>(T[,] arr, int ix, int iy)
{
   return ix < 0 || ix > arr.GetUpperBound(0) ||
          iy < 0 || iy > arr.GetUpperBound(1) ? 
         default(T) : arr[ix,iy];
}
```

Comment: So I just surround the array with padding? If so, is there a way to do it without iterating through it manually?